# Solving ODE $g(\eta)''+\eta/2 \cdot g(\eta)'-n\cdot g(\eta)=0$; BC: $g(0)=1$ and $g(\infty)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, boundary-value-problem, fluid-dynamics

I'm lost! How would I solve $$g(\eta)''+\eta/2 \cdot g(\eta)'-n\cdot g(\eta)=0$$

with BC $$g(0)=1$$ and $$g(\infty)=0$$

Comment: how did you come to that conclusion :D?

Comment: I wanted more like the way to get there or an Ansatz, to solve it by pen and paper

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk, so are you saying that the solution doesn't depend on $n$? This is very strange

Comment: n ist just a real constant, should be n=0,1,2,3... it's tricky because of $$\eta/2 f(\eta)$$

Answer (score 0):

An attempt at solution.

Let's make a transformation for some $a$:

$$g(\eta)=f(\eta)e^{a\eta^2}$$

$$g'=(f'+ 2a \eta f)e^{a\eta^2}$$

$$g''=(f''+ 2a \eta f'+2a f+2a \eta f'+4a^2 \eta^2 f)e^{a\eta^2}=(f''+ 4a \eta f'+2a (1+2a\eta^2)  f)e^{a\eta^2}$$

After substitution we obtain:

$$f''+ 4a \eta f'+2a (1+2a\eta^2)  f+\frac{1}{2} \eta (f'+ 2a \eta f)-nf=0$$

Or:

$$f''+ (4a+1/2) \eta f'+(2a-n+a(1+4a)\eta^2)  f=0$$

We can now pick $a$ to get rid of the first derivative:

$$a=-\frac{1}{8}$$

$$f(\eta)=g(\eta) e^{\eta^2/8}$$

Which gives us:

$$f''-\left(n+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{16}\eta^2 \right)  f=0$$

> $$f''-\frac{1}{16}\left(4(4n+1)+\eta^2 \right)  f=0 \tag{1}$$

This equation has a general solution in the form of [parabolic cylinder functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_cylinder_function).

So in principle, we have solved the problem, and now only need to apply the boundary conditions.

---

However, the boundary conditions pose some challenge. The first one is simple enough.

$$f(0)=1$$

But the second one we can't really guess, because for $\eta \to \infty$ the exponential factor blows up, and we don't know enough about $g(x)$ to figure out what is the limit:

$$\lim_{\eta \to \infty} g(\eta) e^{\eta^2/8} = ?$$

Unless there's some way to apply this boundary condition correctly to (1), we are back to the drawing board.

---

**Update:**

I tried to use the Mathematica ODE solver with the second initial condition:

$$f(\eta_m)=0, \qquad \eta_m  \gg 1$$

For example $\eta_m =100$. The convergence is very good, i.e. the solutions for different but large  $\eta_m$ agree very well.

So I think this may be the way to solve the original equation.

Comment: Wow, thank you!